# jQuery .load on tablerow is messing up table; adding an extra tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, html-table

I'm using jQuery to refresh a row in my table on an input change. This is the basic html of my row:

```
<tr id="TestCaseNameDataRow">
    <td><input value="some value that will be refreshed"></td>
    <td><select></select></td> // select that gets populated based on the above input 
</tr>
```

Here is my javascript for refreshing the table row:

```
$j('#TestCaseNameDataRow').load(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + ' #TestCaseNameDataRow', function(){
    // callback function       
});
```

However, after the load finishes my html looks like this:

```
<tr id="TestCaseNameDataRow">
    <tr id="TestCaseNameDataRow">
        <td><input value="some value that will be refreshed"></td>
        <td><select></select></td> // select that gets populated based on the above input 
    </tr>
</tr>
```

Why is `.load()` doubling the table row? How do I stop it? It's throwing off the appearance of my table.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are returning the whole row from the load call. Try this to see:

```
$j('#TestCaseNameDataRow').load(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + ' #TestCaseNameDataRow', function(response, status, xhr){ 
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

if you see the whole tr in the console then you are going to want to change what the server is bringing back, or target your .load on the parent table.

Comment: I know I'm returning the whole row, but I don't understand why it's putting it inside the original tr, instead of replacing the original tr

Comment: That is what .load() does. It populates the element it's called on. if you do 
$j('#tableID').load(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + ' #TestCaseNameDataRow');

it should do what you are looking for.

Comment: You could also do:

$j("#TestCaseNameDataRow").replaceWith(data);

where data is coming from your sever via $.get or $http

$j.get("window.location.href.split('?')[0] + ' #TestCaseNameDataRow'", function(data) {
     $j("#TestCaseNameDataRow").replaceWith(data);
});